# Cartoon/anime about kids exploring a haunted house/school

Tags: story-identification, anime, horror, cartoon, ghost

I hope paranormal/horror fiction is counted as fantasy here.

I am pretty sure it came out sometime in the 2000s or maybe like very late 90s even though I remember coming across this show in 2014 I think.

It was animated, probably a cartoon, but could have been anime. All I remember is it was, or at least what I saw of it was, about this class either on a field trip or on their own going to like this spooky or haunted house(or possibly school), probably at night. It is possible it was not the whole class, but it was several students at least. I think they were trying to find something supernatural possibly. I remember people saying it was a bit edgy/scary or something for a kids show.

The only character I half remember is like a Emo/Goth girl, though I think there may have been a black nerdy boy as well.

No, not The Magic School Bus. Might be the English dub of Ghost Stories, but I doubt it. Not Corpse Party either. Was in English or at least was dubbed in it.

Comment: Do you remember anything else about the story? On its own exploring a haunted school doesn't narrow it down a lot, because this is an extremely common episodic subplot.

Comment: I think it was Western cartoon styled and for kids, not much more I remember. That being said, I think I found it, it is called 'Freak School'(I need to check), but I might be remembering something else as the plot is not that close to what I remember. @Cubic